# : cause 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: http, http-status-code-406

I get `406 Not Acceptable` on:

```
/process.php?return=http://blog
```

but not on:

```
/process.php?return=http//blog
```

only difference is `:`

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the colon with `%3A` like this:

```
/process.php?return=http%3A//blog
```

Depending on what you're doing with the URL, you might also find that escaping the slashes with `%2F` is a good idea:

```
/process.php?return=http%3A%2F%2Fblog
```

See "Reserved characters" here: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm for more information.

Comment: Error still exists in `/process.php?return=http%3A//blog` but not on `/process.php?return=http3A//blog`so `%` make 406 too

Comment: That's very odd.  Perhaps there's a more detailed error message in your web server logs?

Comment: log is empty too. `SecFilterEngine Off` can be a solution?